# Can $n$ variables ever have more than $n$ unique satisfiable constraints?

Tags: optimization, constraints

Assuming you have $n$ variables, how many maximum **independent** satisfiable constraints can you have? What I mean by independent is that the equations all express unique constraints, s.t for example $x + y = 2$ and $2x + 2y = 4$ would not count as two unique constraints.

My thinking is that outside of mathematics, you can have as many satisfiable constraints between elements of a set as there are non-mutually exclusive relationships between those elements.

For example, let's say we're talking about two people $A$ and $B$. You could say that you want to find two people such that $A$ is taller than $B$, *and* $B$ is richer than $A$, *and* $A$ is stronger than $B$, *and* $A$ is hairier than $B$, etc...

However, let's say you have two variables $x$ and $y$. If we for now constrain ourselves to the real numbers and all of the operations we have on that set,
it seems from what I remember being told in school (and I can't find a counterexample), that even though we have many different kinds of operators and ways to express numbers (powers, exponents, logs, addition, multiplication, etc...), we can't have more unique satisfiable constraints than we have variables.

**Is this always true**? (what about if we add complex numbers?)

**Is there an intuitive way to understand why** (whether or not it's true)?

Does it say something about common fundamental nature between certain operators as far as the kind of relationship they express?

Comment: This seems borderline tautological to me. If  I have $n$ independent constraints, I've restricted $n$ degrees of freedom. Your definition of "independent" in the first paragraph is so broad that this trivial result seems unavoidable.

Comment: I don't mean constraint in the sense of "we have $x$ and $y$ and let $x=3$", where you lose a degree of freedom in the dimension of $x$. I'm talking about relationship constraints, where for ex you have $x + y > 5$. I'm not sure there's a difference with what you're saying, though.

Comment: You're going to have to define your terms more carefully, I think. $x=5$ and $x+y=5$ both eliminate a degree of freedom. And now that you've offered an *inequality* as an example, well, all bets are off. After all, I can just do $x \geq k$, $k=1,2,3,\dots, ...$ and have an arbitrary number of constraints on just one variable. So how shall you define "independent" then?

Comment: I guess I was thinking that any relationship has to include the $n$ variables. In your example, you wouldn't be able to define $k = 1, 2, 3, ....$. You would only be able to constrain the relationship between $x$ and $k$ as two variables.

Comment: That's not a particularly useful distinction in practice. I mean, $x=3$, $y=5$ is as legitimate a pair of linear equations as $x+y=8$, $y-x=2$, and they yield the same values of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I guess I'm not really interested in the practice (if I understand what you mean by practice). I wanted to try to get an intuitive high level understanding for why the number of unique satisfiable constraints we can apply on a relationship between variables is limited in a certain way.